# How can i get the manufacturers from all products?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

The following

```
model.Manufacturers = PagedData.Products.Manufacturers.Select(t => new Manufacturer {  ManufacturerID = t.ManufacturerID, ManufacturerName = t.ManufacturerName }).AsEnumerable();
```

returns

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Manufacturers' and no extension method 'Manufacturers'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

While this one, works partially as expected, since it fetches the manufacturers for the first product found.

```
 var firstOrDefault = PagedData.Products.FirstOrDefault();
 if (firstOrDefault != null) model.Manufacturers = firstOrDefault.Manufacturers.Select(t => new Manufacturer {  ManufacturerID = t.ManufacturerID, ManufacturerName = t.ManufacturerName }).AsEnumerable();
```

How can i have the Manufacturers of all products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because `Products` is a collection of a certain class, but you're trying to access a specific property as if it were only a single instance of the class.

You can either iterate through the list:

```
foreach(var product in PagedData.Products)
{
    model.Manufacturers.AddRange(
        product.Manufacturers.Select(t => new Manufacturer
                                              {
                                                  ManufacturerID = t.ManufacturerID,
                                                  ManufacturerName = t.ManufacturerName
                                              }));
}
```

Or flatten the list using LINQ:

```
model.Manufacturers =
    PagedData.Products.SelectMany(p => p.Manufacturers
                                        .Select(t => new Manufacturer
                                                         {
                                                             ManufacturerID = t.ManufacturerID,
                                                             ManufacturerName = t.ManufacturerName})
                                        .AsEnumerable());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to flatten your list first. You can do so bu using the `SelectMany` method.

```
model.Manufacturers = PagedData.Products
                               .SelectMany(product=>product.Manufacturers)
                               .Select(m => new Manufacturer 
                                {
                                    ManufacturerID = m.ManufacturerID, 
                                    ManufacturerName = m.ManufacturerName 
                                })
                               .AsEnumerable();
```

From your code I assumed that each products has a list of manufacturers. Based on this, it's clear that Products.Manufactures is a list of list of manufacturers (or a sequence of a sequence of manufacturers). So this is why you have to flatten your list.